# How to check whether specific IP address is connected to the network

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, wifi

I want to create an application to find whether a specific IP address on a network is online. I would already know the IP. I am pretty new to C#, but was wondering if anyone could just give me a simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: You want to retrieve IP address which you already know?

Comment: yes @Carl right now just one

Comment: If you already know the IP, what do you need to "find"?

Comment: I want to know if the IP Address is on the network @PrestonGuillot

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Ping ping = new Ping ();
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("000.000.000.000");
PingReply pong = pingSender.Send(address);
```

`pong` object contains information whether it was succesfull or not.

```
if (pong.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
  // your machine at address is up and responding
}
```

A complete program which would use this

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        //change the following ip variable into the ip adress you are looking for
        string ip = " ";
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        PingReply pong = ping.Send(address);
        if (pong.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip + " is up and running.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LUKER I have edited the answer with a complete example.